# React-hook-form - How to add a styled-components child to <form>?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, react-hook-form

I have a react-hook-form.
This form has a similar structure:

```
return (
    <AppLayout>
      <CreateAccContainer>
        <Container header="Create account">
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} key={key}>
            <CreateSellerAccountContainer>
              <CustomerDataBox />
              <CreateAccountForm formState={formState} register={register} />
            </CreateSellerAccountContainer>
            <Button fullWidth disabled={!formState.isDirty}>
              Create account
            </Button>
          </form>
        </Container>
      </CreateAccContainer>
    </AppLayout>
  )
```

The `CreateAccountForm` has a similar structure:

```
export const CreateAccountForm = ({ formState, register } : any) => {
  const { errors } = formState

  return (
    <SubFormContainer>
        <Checkbox
          {...register('xyz')}
          label="I agree"
          errorMsg={errors?.[xyz].message as string}
        />
        <Checkbox
          {...register('xyz2')}
          label="I agree 2"
          errorMsg={errors?.[xyz2].message as string}
        />
etc
```

And `SubFormContainer` is:

```
export const SubFormContainer = styled.form(
  () => css`
    width: 100%;
  `
)
```

If I have that structure, the forms works well. The "defaultValues" are being read. It means that there is a checkbox that has to be default checked. And it works. But in the console I read `Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <form> cannot appear as a descendant of <form>.`

If I change it to `SubFormContainer = styled.div` then the warning disappears, but the default states of the checkboxes and other inputs are not being read/rendered.

How can I:
-avoid form in form
-make the `SubFormContainer` read the values as part of the main form?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using [FormProvider](https://react-hook-form.com/docs/formprovider)?

You could also use `fieldset` element instead of `div`

Comment: that's really strange. I implemented both of them. `FormProvider` and `fieldset`. Strange thing is that the default values appear only if I add a space for example after the comma `const { register, formState } = useFormContext()` - the component rerenders and it works. But if I refresh the page it doesn't work, all checkboxes are unselected. If I readd or remove the space, it works again.

Comment: I found out the `FormProvider` works with `fieldset` and `div` if I add a `useEffect(() => {  setKey((prev) => prev + 1)}, [])` and I add the key to `< SubFormContainer key={key}>` - any idea how to make it more "elegant" to avoid the key?

Comment: Could you also show the Checkbox component?

Comment: Unfortunately that piece of code cannot be shown. However if we are looking for something specific, please let me know and I'll check it or show little pieces

Comment: I would try making sure the [default values are set on form](https://react-hook-form.com/docs/useform#defaultValues) and debugging the output of `register('checkbox_name')`, whether it has all the necessary props for your `Checkbox` with correct value

Comment: Yes, the default values are set on form. `register('checkbox_name')` has only: name, onBlur, ref, onChange.

Comment: And does the `ref` receive correct ref?

Comment: the whole Checbox component is wrapped into `forwardRef`. Then `forwardRef` is sent to the Props of the styled components CheckBoxInput input`type="checkbox"` component via ref={forwardedRef} if I `console.log("ref", forwardedRef)` I get `ref (ref) => { if (ref) { register(name, options); field = get(_fields, name); const fieldRef = isUndefined(ref.value)...`